# dont know why i am getting extra qoutes in postman response when i return by JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

Tags: c#, json.net, postman

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

but getting in postman response like extra qoutes and escape sequence in string so that can not be parse in json again

```
"{\"Data\":null,\"Message\":null,\"Status\":0}"
```

Comment: You need to show a little bit more about the method that is serializing response

Comment: If the two linked duplicates don't answer your question, please do [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and we can re-open the question for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a controller and using SerializeObject(response) it will return a string object, so it's normal you get the extra quote at the start/end of your JSON.

If you are in a ASP.NET controller you should juste return the response directly like this :

```
return response
```

And the framework will take care of serializing it into JSON (or even another format if needed). It's not a concern you should take care of.